# Change background image in sencha touch

Tags: css, sencha-touch, panel

I'm a beginner in sencha touch, so I'm having some basic questions.

I have added a background image to a panel in css:

```
#inputPanel{
    background:url(../i/input-bg.png) no-repeat left top;
}
```

Every time the panel is shown, I want to change the background image:

```
this.inputPanel = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
    cls:'panel',
    id:'inputPanel',
    items:[],
    dockedItems:[],
    listeners:{
        beforeshow:function(){
            if(showImageAAA)
              // Change the background image to AAA
            else
              // Change the background image to BBB
        },
    }
});
```

Is there any easy way to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do below

```
this.inputPanel = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
    cls:'panel',
    id:'inputPanel',
    items:[],
    dockedItems:[],
    listeners:{
        beforerender:function(){
            if(showImageAAA)
              // Change the background image to AAA
               this.style="background:url(../i/input-bgAAA.png) no-repeat left top;";
            else
              // Change the background image to BBB
               this.style="background:url(../i/input-bgBBB.png) no-repeat left top;";
        },
    }
});
```

Hope this help!

Comment: Thanks Scott. Please see my comments in the other answer.

Comment: The second time, you should get the inputPanel and set its style at get call show inputPanel if you was hide before.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can set the "style" or "bodyStyle" property of the panel.

Comment: Thanks. Could you be more specific?

Comment: When the "beforeshow" event is fired, it's given a couple of parameters: the component that is about to be shown and an options object. http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel. So change that event listener to "beforeshow:function(panel, options)" and then in the function you can something like "panel.style = 'background-color:red;'"

Comment: Thanks for the update. I've tried it, but it seems that the style is changed only at the first time the panel is shown. If I close the panel, change "showImageAAA", and open the panel again, the background stays the same. But if I change "showImageAAA" before the first time the panel is shown, the background is changed corrected. So is there anything I should do before the second time to show the panel?

Comment: What do you mean by "close"? You generally only close windows, and even then you set the closeAction to hide so that you're really hiding it. Are you actually hiding the panel? Or is this in a card layout where you're setting a different panel as the active item?

Comment: Yes, I was just hiding the panel.